# $f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and $|f(z)|\le 1$, we need to show

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ and $|f(z)|\le 1$, we need to show

$$\frac{f(0)-|z|}{1-|z f(0)|}\le |f(z)|\le \frac{f(0)+|z|}{1+|z f(0)|} $$

I am not able to proceed with Schwarz lemma/Pick lemma, could any one tell me how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conway - Somewhere near page 130. There is a whole section on functions that map $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{D}$.

The case of when $|f(0)|=1$ must be argued separately (use the Maximum Modulus Principal). Assume $|f(0)|\not=1$ and define $$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}f(z)}.$$ If $$\phi_{f(0)}(z)=\frac{z-f(0)}{1-\overline{f(0)}z},$$ then $g=\phi\circ f$ satisfies Schwarz lemma, since both $\phi$ and $f$ map the unit disc to itself (showing $\phi$ maps the unit disc to itself is a little tricky, but in general this class of $\phi_\alpha$'s is very special). Thus $|g(z)|\le |z|$ for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$. If you perform the triangle inequality in two different ways you get: $$|f(z)|-|f(0)|\le |z|+|z|\cdot |f(0)|\cdot |f(z)| \\ |f(0)|-|f(z)|\le |z|+|z|\cdot |f(0)|\cdot |f(z)| $$ which gives the inequalities that you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps an easy way to show that $\phi$ maps $D$ into $D$ would be to show that it maps $1$, $i$ and $-i$ into numbers with norm $1$. Since Möbius transformations send circles into circles, $\phi$ maps the unitary disk into itself. Since it may only map the interior of $D$ into either itself or its exterior, evaluating $\phi$ at $z=0$ shows the former to be true.

I hope I could be of help.