# Schwarz's Lemma and extensions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was assigned this problem: (which I here present verbatim)

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function of the unit disk unto itself. Prove that $|f'(0)|\le 1$.

Isn't it also necessary to assume that $f(0)=0$ for the above to be true in general?

Problem 2 of [this](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~olga/mat542/hw7_542.pdf) link states it in a way that reduces to the above result when $f(0)=0$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it is not necessary to assume $f(0)=0$. Hint: compose $f$ with a fractional linear transformation that sends $f(0)$ back to $0$. Apply the Schwarz lemma. Use the chain rule for the derivatives.

Comment: Sorry I am somewhat rusty on Möbius transformations (you mean möbius transformations, right?), what would the general form of a fractional linear mapping satisfying the above?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/412298/